# Multiplos RewriteRules para 3rdparty e rotas

Tags: apache, htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewrite

Tenho um arquivo `.htaccess` que adiciona `PATH_INFO` in the `index.php` file (para o sistema de rotas):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d

RewriteRule ^(?!index\.php(/.*|$))([a-zA-Z0-9\-\/.]+)$ index\.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Isto funciona perfeitamente com o meu sistema de rotas que está no index.php

O problema é que eu quero usar *softtwares de terceiro* (3rdparty) ao mesmo tempo que o sistema de rotas, então fiz isto no *.htaccess*:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d

RewriteRule ^(?!3rdparty/.*|index\.php(/.*|$))(.*)$ 3rdparty/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Este RewriteRule tenta acessar arquivos que estão na pasta "3rdparty" reescrevendo para não apresentar o `3rdparty` na url, mas se o arquivo ou pasta não existirem dentro de 3rdparty então o sistema deve-se usar as rotas.

Exemplo, se acessar `http://localhost/folder1/` irá mostrar o conteudo de do arquivo `/var/www/3rdparty/folder1/`, mas se o arquivo não existir na pasta `3rdparty` então deverá usar o sistema de rotas.

### Estrutura de pasta

Isto é apenas um exemplo

```
project
├── index.php
├── .htaccess
└── 3rdparty
    ├── folder1
    └── folder2
        ├── file1.html
        └── file2.html
```

O que eu quero é acessar outros arquivos PHP sem precisar digitar algo como `http://localhost/3rdparty/something...`

Exemplos (veja a estrutura das pastas acima):

- `http://example/project/folder1` mostrará o conteudo de `http://example/project/3rdparty/folder1`
- `http://example/project/folder2` mostrará o conteudo de `http://example/project/3rdparty/folder2/`
- `http://example/project/folder2/file1.html` mostrará o conteudo de `http://example/project/3rdparty/folder2/file1.html`
- `http://example/project/folder2/file2.html` mostrará o conteudo de `http://example/project/3rdparty/folder2/file2.html`
- `http://example/project/folder3/file3.html` (url não existente na pasta 3rdparty) mostrará o conteudo de `http://example/project/index.php/folder3/file3.html`

Como posso fazer isto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue os comentário no arquivo para entender como funciona

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Troque está linha por / ou pelo nome da pasta que estará
    # usando o seu framework e pastas ex.: /laravel (http://localhost/laravel)
    # ou /cakephp (http://localhost/cakephp)
    # no meu caso /project (http://localhost/project)

    RewriteBase /project

    # Está linha irá liberar acesso aos arquivos estáticos sem precisar
    # digitar public no endereço, como por exemplo:
    # http://localhost/project/css/file.css
    # http://localhost/project/js/file.js
    # http://localhost/project/images/file.jpg

    RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [QSA,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # Se não for em public então direciona para o 3rdparty
    RewriteRule ^(?!(index\.php|public|3rdparty)/.*)(.*)$ 3rdparty/$2 [QSA,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # Se não existir nada em 3rdparty então usa o sistema de rotas
    RewriteRule ^(?!index\.php/.*)3rdparty/([A-Za-z0-9\/\-.]+)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

> **Nota:** Removido `\w` do exemplo por questões de SEO, pois ele aceita `_` underline, veja os detalhes a seguir (acaso queira modificar os tipos de caracteres aceitos).

### Padrões individuais

- `\s` Casa espaços em branco, `\n`\r ou `\t`.
- `\S` Negação de `\s:` casa o que não for espaço em branco, `\n` `\r` ou `\t`.
- `\w` Casa letras, dígitos, ou `_`.
- `\W` Negação de `\w`
- `\d` Casa dígitos, de 0 a 9.
- `\D` Negação de `\d`

### Âncoras

- `\b` Casa a separação de palavras, o que inclui também o começo `^` e o fim `$` da cadeia de caracteres testada. A definição dos caracteres que formam palavras varia de acordo com a implementação, mas é seguro assumir pelo menos `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. Havendo suporte, o atalho `\w` é uma alternativa válida. O Java é uma notável exceção na medida em que suporta `\b` mas não `\w`. Notar que apesar de parecida com os limites de palavras definidos pela POSIX, esta sequência de escape não distingue o começo e o final da palavra, somente a separação em si.
- `\B` Negação de `\b`
- `\A` Casa o começo da cadeia de caracteres. Numa situação de múltiplas linhas, não casa o começo das linhas seguintes, o que a difere de `^`.
- `\Z` Casa o fim da cadeia de caracteres ou a posição logo antes da quebra de linha do fim da cadeia. Numa situação de múltiplas linhas, não casa o fim das linhas seguintes, o que a difere de `$`.
- `\z` Casa o fim da cadeia de caracteres.

<sub>**Fonte:** [http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expressão_regular](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express%C3%A3o_regular)</sub>